# How to get the Stored Procedure's returned table's structure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, schema

I am working with SQL Server to store Stored Procedures data into *temp* tables.
There are data-type mismatch errors. The stored procedure is too long and complex that I can't figure out each and every field's type.

Is there any way to figure out to see the structure of SPs returned table?

Below code I am trying to figure out the schema.

```
SELECT
p.name ,
OBJECT_NAME(OBject_ID) 'ProductionLog', 
p.parameter_id ,
p.user_type_id ,
t.name 'TypeName',
p.max_length ,
p.precision ,
p.scale ,
p.is_output 
FROM
sys.parameters p
INNER JOIN 
sys.types t ON p.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
```

Comment: There was nothing unclear in this. I need to know about the schema. that's why I  put it here if any one has already done,so he/she may suggest.

Comment: Who so ever put their comments, must read out what is being asked in the question, rather in hurry to down-vote or score their number in review.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have done, in C# application.

```
public static DataTable SchemaReader(string tableName)
    {
        string sql = "<SP_NAME>";//replace this with your store procedure name   
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("packet size=4096;user id=<DB_NAME>;pwd=<PASSWORD>;data source=<DB_SOURCE>\\;persist security info=False;initial catalog=<DB_NAME>"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PARAM1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  "2015-04-13";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PARAM2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "2015-04-15";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PARAM3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "12:00 PM";                                                               
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();                
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
            return schema;
        }

    }
```

Preview Data-Table, you will all the properties.